# Do I need permission to use the SE API for a commercial app?

Tags: discussion, api, release

I recently developed a mobile app using the publicly available API of one of the Stack Exchange sites.

Do I need to obtain permission from Stack Exchange before releasing the app to the public? Can I make money from this (or any other) app that uses the Stack Exchange API? I am trying to be cautious so that I don't end up with regrets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need permission to use the API commercially so long as you're in compliance with the [license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) the served content is under.

Attribution is required, and if index-able from a search engine [additional constraints apply](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/).